# Imported SVG as <object> contain onclick events how to handle them in Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, svg

I'm struggling with this and it seems that I loose all ideas.

In angular component I'm loading SVG from external resources as

```
<object type="image/svg+xml"  [data]="svgURL"></object>
```

Loaded SVG object contains items like this one:

```
<g onclick="onClickArea(evt,'3')></g>
```

So when I click on SVG specific area I'm getting error:

```
0276a76ee45640eba80002580a126a38:158 Uncaught ReferenceError: onClickArea is not defined
    at SVGGElement.onclick
```

Is it possible and how should it be to register function onClickArea in Angular component and listen for onclick events at SVG.

I tried to register onClickArea at window object but it doesn't work.

```
(<any>window).onClickArea = function() {
    console.log('test');
};
```

Comment: Your code should work, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-plbasx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) (the method could also have been defined in the class constructor). Please note that a `"` is missing at the end of the `onclick` in your code sample.

Comment: @ConnorsFan it is going to work in your example, but in my example <g> tags that contains onclick event are not added directly in angular html file. They are imported as <object> where  content of SVG contains these onclick events which I can't to caught in Angular component.

Comment: If you have control on the SVG content, try: `onclick="top.onClickArea('hello', 3)"`, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://angular-object-svg-content-queryselector-ezfy1d.stackblitz.io/). The stackblitz with the original code is found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-object-svg-content-queryselector-ezfy1d?file=src%2Fassets%2Fnew.svg), but it has to be executed in full window mode.

Answer (score 1):

you can add click event to element like this:

```
var elements= document.getElementsByTagName("g");

for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].addEventListener("click", (event: Event) => {
            alert("click event");
        });
}
```

Below is a stackBliz link which does the same : you will get event on click of g tag

https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-izqcuz?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: What is "your_html" in this case?

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("g") returns empty array of HTMLCollection. The reason of that is because I load SVG as a <object> not as a <svg> as you did in above example. Because as I understand <object> create something like an iframe in a DOM. 

Could you try your example with <object> where SVG is loaded from external resources. @Amrit

Comment: i think replacing "g" with "object " in var elements= document.getElementsByTagName("g"); should work